# JLabel not showing up onto JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

For some reason when the condition of getSelector is equal to 2 is reached (I know for a fact this if statements condition is being reached because of System.out.println(""); so don't say that the statement is not getting reached) but when the condition is achieved for some reason the JLabel (problem) is not showing up on the JPanel (panel). (NOTE: The JPanel has been added to my JFrame) Why is this happening, I used the validate, and repaint methods. Thank you very much and happy 4th of July :-)!

NOTE: ALSO THE TIMERCLASS OBJECT'S CALLED METHODS ARE WORKING PROPERLY SO I KNOW THAT IS NOT THE SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM!

EDIT: I have now added all of the code so this could help to possibly answer my problem's source

Comment: what happens if instead of callin panel.validate you call panel.invalidate() ?

Comment: Not sure, let me quickly check.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix anything.

Comment: do you have enough visual space on your panel ? what kind of layout out are you using ?

Comment: It should be panel.revalidate(); But that aside why do you want to remove and add the label every time

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) Tip: Add @user3887735 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Yes I do, I know this actually because when I is equal to 14 I can see the JLabel (problem) so I know something wrong is happening.

Comment: Also when referring other persons use @MauricioGracia or whomever it is by @ personname so that the person will be notified

Comment: Revalidate does not do anything else either.

Comment: Are you running this code inside an event handler? Please follow Andrew Thompson's advice and rewrite your program into an MCVE or SSCCE. It's hard to help without being able to run and see.

Comment: @Madhan I am not removing anything accept when i is equal to 14, I am simply trying to re validate the JLabel (problem).

Comment: Here now I am providing all of the code

Comment: Were you really adding this panel to the content pane ?? ie getContentPane().add(panel);

Comment: Yes as you can see I added the JPanel panel, to the JFrame frame.

Comment: Here's a way to avoid the vast majority of the confusion you are experiencing now: always instantiate, populate, and validate the JPanel/similar objects, before adding them to your main window (e.g. JFrame). Thereafter, simply pack your JFrame, and show it. In this manner, you'll only need to have a layout in the panel, and you won't need to re-validate every single item you add.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you'd tried to add the panel to the **JFrame** via `frame.add(panel)`. But the correct way of adding a component to the **JFrame** is via its getContentPane() method. ie as per your code it should be like `frame.getContentPane().add(panel)`. Okay ? And also you're setting the panel's layout as null. It means you need to set the size of the component(s) you wish to add to this panel, manually. That is since you're adding the JLabel problem, you need to set the size of that **JLabel** like `problem.setSize(width,height)`. Hope that this would resolve your issue.

Comment: Also remove those panel.validate() and repaint() calls. It wont be necessary though.

Comment: I edited my code with the frame.getContentPane().add(panel) but I do know for a fact that the setSize method not being called is not the answer to my problem because when i is equal to 14 I start seeing the JLabel problem